# Drawer only open in first screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I using the package [flutter_zoom_drawer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_drawer) to create a drawer for my app in Flutter, but I having an issue. When I open the app, he initiates in the home page and the drawer works normally, but when I go to other screen and return to home page the drawer stop working

[image: error gif]

[main.dart code](https://github.com/Gustavo-daCosta/To-Do-App/blob/main/lib/main.dart)

[home_page.dart code](https://github.com/Gustavo-daCosta/To-Do-App/blob/main/lib/screens/home_page.dart)

[drawer.dart code](https://github.com/Gustavo-daCosta/To-Do-App/blob/main/lib/components/drawer.dart)

What I have to do to correct this?

Comment: I have the same issue. do you find the solution ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes, my problem was that the package that I was using force you to create a new class for homepage, something like DrawerWithHomePage class, and to call the home page WITH the drawer I have to call that class, the problem was that when i press the home page button in the drawer i go to HomePage class and dont the DrawerWithHomePage class, and I go to the HomePage class but without the drawer.

This response may be some confusing, but at the end of the day I will anwser my own question with a more elaborate response

Answer (score 0):

I think you have put you onPressed Code inside the small bracket so it is not executing.